# MySQL response as custom text in Smarty.

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I need to query my db and if the response is `1`, I need to display a `yes` if I get a `2`, display a maybe if I get a `3` display no.
I know in php we use constants for this but I don't know how to do it in smarty.
this is the query part

```
$result = select_query("tblemails", "", array("userid" => $userid), "id", "DESC", "0,5");
$lastfivemail = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$lastfivemail[] = array("id" => $data["id"], "security" => $data["security"], "date" => frommysqldate($data["date"], "time"), "subject" => $data["subject"] ? $data["subject"] : "No Subject");
continue;
}
$templatevars["lastfivemail"] = $lastfivemail;
```

the structure is used in whmcs.

```
"security" => $data["security"]
```

returns the 1, 2 or 3 from the db

this is the code used to display

```
<div class="clientssummarybox">
<div class="title">{$_ADMINLANG.clientsummary.emailsheading}</div>
<table class="clientssummarystats" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
{foreach key=num from=$lastfivemail item=email}
<tr class="{cycle values=",altrow"}"><td align="center">{$email.date} - <a href="#" onClick="window.open('clientsemails.php?&displaymessage=true&id={$email.id}','','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">{$email.subject}</a></td></tr>
{foreachelse}
<tr><td align="center">{$_ADMINLANG.clientsummary.noemails}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
</div>

</td><td width="25%" valign="top">
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
{foreach key=num from=$lastfivemail item=email}
<tr class="{cycle values=",altrow"}"><td align="center">{$email.date} - <a href="#" onClick="window.open('clientsemails.php?&displaymessage=true&id={$email.id}','','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">{$email.subject}</a></td>
<td>
{if $email.security eq '1'}
   Yes
{elseif $email.security eq '3'}
   No
{else}
    Other
{/if}
</td></tr>
{foreachelse}
```

[**IF ELSE**](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl)